# C# options pattern custom configuration provider

Tags: c#

I have a problem with initialization of options object which includes array of custom objects, from custom configuration provider class. Which is used with HostBuilder DI container I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-configuration-provider) tutorial but It did not help my use case

I have a following options class

```
public sealed class FooOptions
{
    public Bar[] Bars { get; set; }
}
```

Following options configuration provider class

```
public class FooConfigurationProvider : ConfigurationProvider
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Data = CreateConfiguration();
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string> CreateConfiguration()
    {
        var configuration = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var fooOptionsName = nameof(FooOptions);

        var bars = new Bar[]
        {
            new Bar()
            {
                Blah = "A"
            },
            new Bar()
            {
                Blah = "B"
            }
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < bars.Length; i++)
        {
            configuration.Add($"{fooOptionsName}:Bars:{i}:Blah",
                bars[i].Blah);
        }

        return configuration;
    }
}
```

and here is the Bar class

```
public sealed class Bar
{
    public string Blah { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that FooOptions class Bars property is not initialized for some reason following initialization works with primitive types but not with custom types for some reason.

Does anybody know how to initialize FooOptions class through configuration provider?

Comment: Sorry, but where are you creating an instance of `FooOptions` and then setting `FooOptions` property `Bars` to your initialized `Bar[]` variable `bars` ?

Comment: FooOptions instance is created by HostBuilder DI container I did not include the binding of options to container because It Is just boiler plate code